# Python capture command send to unix, capture output and write to file

Tags: python, file, unix, command, output

```
import subprocess 
cmd = 'ifconfig -a'

p = subprocess.Popen(cmd, shell=True, stderr=subprocess.PIPE)

while True:
    out = p.stderr.read(1)
    if out == '' and p.poll() != None:
        break
    if out != '':
        sys.stdout.write(out)
        sys.stdout.flush()
       <<<HOW TO CMD SENT AND IT'S OUTPUT>>>
        file = open('outputFile.txt', 'w+')
        file.write(out)
        file.close()
```

Comment: what is your question?

Comment: Looking for help on to comment and expand my code to send command, capture the command sent and it's output

Comment: please edit your question, voteup-approve the answer if it helps you and read the tutorial of stack overflow

Comment: mind to point where is the tutorial of stack overflow?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
from subprocess import Popen, PIPE, STDOUT
cmd = ["ifconfig", "-a"]

p = Popen(cmd, stdout=PIPE, stderr=STDOUT)
stdout, stderr = p.communicate()

print stdout
```

capture output and write to file: python ifconfig.py > outputfile.txt